# Where to find domain name to use Azure AD Authentication in application

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-authentication

I'm looking to learn how to set up a Web API to use Azure authentication. This web api will be locally hosted on my network and not in Azure. I simply want to use Azure as a means of authenticating user sign in and token management. I've set up a web api in the past but it used authentication with a locally hosted SQL database. I'm completely new to Azure and am looking for any resources on how to set this up. The end goal is to get something that I can put into the domain box pictured below:

[image: domain]

I have no idea what that is or how to go about getting it. I know this is Stackoverflow but can anyone at least point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do what you're describing.  Assuming you already have an Azure Subscription, sign-in to the Azure portal and open the **Azure Active Directory** blade.  In the Azure Active Directory blade, click on **Custom domain names**.  This will show you what your Azure AD domain is.  Unless you have configured a custom domain for your directory, it will be `<something>.onmicrosoft.com`.  For example,

[image]

Comment: That was it. Once I entered just the domain name and nothing else it worked. Thanks Rick!